# Python Crashes when I am trying to access any date related fields in MailItem COM

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to print emails from Outlook using win32com. The only issue is when I am trying to access `MailItem.SentOn` or `MailItem.ReceivedTime`, Python crashes with windows showing "Python has stopped working" dialog window. What can be the cause of this issue?

Here is my code:

```
import win32com
import win32com.client
import os
import sys
import re
from datetime import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
accounts = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts

inbox = outlook.Folders(accounts[0].DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
folders = inbox.Folders

inbox_messages = folders("Inbox").Items
msg = inbox_messages.GetFirst()

while msg:
    print(msg.SenderEmailAddress)
    print(msg.Subject)
    print (msg.SentOn)
    msg = inbox_messages.GetNext()
```

I am using Office 365 and Python 3.7.0 on Windows 10.

[Error Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaE64.png)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Can you update your question with any error logs?

Comment: Hi. There are no errors. There is a windows error window with two options. Close the program or Debug the program.

Comment: Are you running the code from the a command line? if not do so, you should get a stack trace. i.e. `python myscript.py`

Comment: Yes I am running it from command line and this error window appears when it tries to print the 3rd line for the first email. When I comment out that line it works perfectly.

Comment: Ok. Wrap your code in a `try catch` block and print the exception.

Comment: It does not raise any exceptions. It shows the error window again. It is really strange.

Comment: This means a C-level error. You need Visual Studio and Python debug symbols to diagnose it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug python script that is crashing python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678978/how-to-debug-python-script-that-is-crashing-python)

Comment: I will try Visual Studio. PDB did not show anything and python just crashed like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this same issue.  My script works fine in Python 3.6.5, but fails in 3.7.0

Comment: You are awesome!!! Basically the issue is only with 3.7.0. I have tried Python 3.6.6 and it is working fine.

Comment: Glad to help.  I hope this information makes its way back to the developers, but I don't quite know how to make that happen.

Comment: The issue is fixed in the new release of pywin32.

Answer (score 0):

so not all mails will have SenderEmailAddress and SentOn.
I tried your program on my inbox and it seems to crash on a mail that was generated by outlook - a undeliverable mail generated by outlook:

```
Your message to xxxx@xxxx.com couldn't be delivered.
A custom mail flow rule created by an admin at xxx.onmicrosoft.com has blocked your message.
```

.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx\outl.py", line 24, in <module>
    print (msg.SentOn)
  File "xxx\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: GetNext.SentOn
```

not sure why it crashes python for you but a crash with stack for me but i think you should handle the case where the attributes can be missing.

Comment: Hi hmad. Thank you for your response, I think in your case it actually went over some other emails before giving you this message. Actually in my original code, there is a line to check the subject which makes sure that the email will have a sender and SentOn property attached to it. In my case, the first email that is read by the code, will crash python on accessing SentOn property. Just commenting that line fixes everything.