# How to force trace run my program as module, not script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, pdb

I need to run my program as `python3 -m directory.__init__`, but [trace](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/trace.html) does not allow to do so. It forces me to run it like `python3 directory/__init__.py`

I am running trace like `python3 -u -m trace -t directory/__init__.py` ([How to debug python script that is crashing python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678978/how-to-debug-python-script-that-is-crashing-python)) but trace is not running my script as a module:

```
    from . import mymodule
ImportError: cannot import name 'mymodule'
```

Then, all my relative imports (as `from . import mymodule`) are failing.

The same problem was recently fixed in Python 3.7, but for the `pdb` module: [How to debug a Python module run with python -m from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265835/how-to-debug-a-python-module-run-with-python-m-from-the-command-line), now I can run `pdb` like

```
python3 -m pdb -m directory.__init__
```